# Php storing url image path in MySQL DB

Tags: php

I am trying to store URL Image paths into MySQL DB. But i am not getting any results with my code.

- Why is it not storing anything?
- Would it be better just to store the image name or the entire path? 
  target example: "www.example.com/medium/imagename.jpg"

**Table Name: urlimage**

```
id: autoincrement
image_name 



Php code for inserting data into DB
<?php

$images = explode(',', $_GET['i']);

$path = Configuration::getUploadUrlPath('medium', 'target');


if(is_array($images)){

    $objDb = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
    $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `urlImage` (`image_name`) VALUES ";

  foreach ($images as $image) {

    //echo '<div><p>' . $path . $image . '</p><img src="' . $path . $image . '" /></div>';
    $value[] = "(".$path.$image.")"; // collect imagenames
  }

  $sql .= implode(',', $value).";"; //build query

  $objDb->query($sql);   
}

?>
```

Comment: You should store only image file-name in database.

Comment: debug by `print_r($sql)` just before `$objDb->query($sql);`

Comment: Are you getting any errors? In your `php.ini` set `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT` and `display_errors = On` if you have not done so.

Comment: of course, it's better to store filenames instead of entire path. Think about it: Entire path takes lot's memory for the same string... Define simple const or var instead of path

Comment: @diEcho yea after putting what you told me i got: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" for   `$objDb->query($sql);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this; it may work:

```
$value[] = "('".$path.$image."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have error in `$sql`

it must be  `$value[] = "('".$path.$image."')";`

debug with

```
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($sql);echo "</pre>";
```

and if your using **PDO** function then call

[`prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)->[`execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.execute.php)

Comment: yea after putting what you told me i got: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" for `$objDb->query($sql);`